# Stop php re-proccess all when hit refresh

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo, database-connection

I'm here again with high traffic problems, i'm having a problem with "Sleep" thread on Mysql, after searching a lot i'm on my way to solve this problem.

I make sure db connection is killed after the use, i solve part of the problem, now when my code go to right path he just open few sleep thread and close fast, but i still having problem with "Sleep" threads, i observe and get lots of sleep when i hit f5 multiple times and it do all the proccess again, and the same user enter on competition.

So i've think about it and maybe got a solution, but don't know to apply.

I think if the user HIT f5, i just kill all proccess that same user request last time and starting over again, or just don't start again just give the result from the last time. I can't block "f5", so if i press f5 many times he just put sleep until the timeout kill it becouse i think zend can't manage that connection becouse the code is gone.

Im right?

Sorry about my english, and appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: How do you make sure that the DB connection is killed?

Comment: I was let it to zend, but now i changed things to set 'null' to pdo object after fetch the results.

Comment: I think i need something using register_shutdown_function to kill the useless proccess. But i can't figure it to work. Im kinda crazy with this.